# Использование минимального и максимального значения типовых операций

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, анализ-данных

Имеется следующий датасет:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно для каждой станции, взять время начала операции 1 и время завершения операции 3 и объединить в новую операцию?

Ожидаемый обновленный датасет на изображении ниже:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пример датасета:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kiQtuh9mcYj2zsVGWDMrXHeIHcShxyZJ/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=100335429201323787767&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: Можете пояснить откуда взялись значения в столбце `Finish` в ожидаемом датасете? По какой формуле вы их получаете?

Comment: Finish = это время начала операции (Start) + длительность операции (Duration)

В ожидаемом датасете для United Operation это:
Start = время начала Opeeration 1
Finish = время завершения Операции 3
Duration = сумма длительностей Операций 1,2,3

Comment: `Finish = время завершения Операции 3` - судя по данным в ожидаемом датасете это не так. Для `Station 1 / Operation 3` - `Finish` -> `10`, а в ожидаемом датасете - 12 - почему так?

Comment: Судя по вашему желаемому датасету, вы хотите получить не время завершения всех трех операций, а общую их продолжительность.

Comment: @AlexMorgan, [что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сделать так:

```
ops = ['Operation 1','Operation 2','Operation 3']

agg_funcs = dict(
  Start=("Start", "first"),
  Duration=("Duration", "sum"),
  Finish=("Duration", "sum"),
  Color=("Color", "last"),
)

tmp = df.assign(op=df.groupby("Place").cumcount()).query("Airport not in @ops")

x = (df
     .query("Airport in @ops")
     .groupby(["Place","Length", "Train type", "Operation type", "Arr/Dep"])
     .agg(**agg_funcs)
     .reset_index()
     .assign(Airport="United Operation", op=-1))

res = x.append(tmp).sort_values(["Place", "op"]).drop(columns="op")[df.columns]
```

результат:

```
In [343]: res
Out[343]:
       Place  Length  Train type Operation type           Airport Arr/Dep  Start  Duration  Finish  Color
0   Station1      21         222           Main  United Operation     Arr      0        12      12  Green
3   Station1      21         333           Main       Operation 4     Arr      8         6      14    Red
4   Station1      21         333     ADDITIONAL       Operation 5     Arr     12         7      19  Green
1   Station2      25         222           Main  United Operation     Arr      0        11      11    Red
8   Station2      25         333           Main       Operation 4     Arr      6         9      15  Green
9   Station2      25         333     ADDITIONAL       Operation 5     Arr     12         7      19    Red
2   Station3      27         222           Main  United Operation     Arr      0        12      12  Green
13  Station3      27         333           Main       Operation 4     Arr      8        13      21    Red
14  Station3      27         333     ADDITIONAL       Operation 5     Arr     12        11      23  Green
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, именно такая реализация и ожидалась!